# T4 Editor for Visual Studio 11 beta?

Tags: t4, visual-studio-2012

Is there a T4 editor that works with Visual Studio 11 beta 1 yet?

I have no doubt tangible will update, but one doesn't seem to be available yet.

Comment: It's kind of sad that MS didn't build it in since T4 is so cool.

Comment: Totally agree - I use T4 extensively and was surprised that intellisense / color coding wasn't native in the 2011 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like tangible is the first out of the gate.  They posted T4 tools for VS 11.

You can get it here:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e2dde6-5408-42c2-bc92-ac36942bbee9